# Best approach to handling strings.xml in an Android project

Tags: android, xml

Wanted to ask about the **strings.xml** in an Android project. I often see that the normal usage is to put all text for the entire App in the strings.xml. And I have also seen that strings.xml holds system strings and the rest is stored in xml files that have the name of the class. like this:

> ActivityMain.java (having many text strings for user to read)
>
> activity_main.xml (holding all text strings for ActivityMain.java)

I look trough [android-best-practices](https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices) but finds no mentioning of this.

Maybe this does not matter but what is your view on this, pros and cons?

Comment: Best way for storing string is SharedPreference, it will store string and other primitive data as a key value for in xml file

Comment: Your right thanks, I changed my Q titel

Answer (score 3):

To manage the strings for your project, the best approachment (From my not quite long experience) is to split the strings related to it's usage.

For example,
if you have 2 Activity: `MainActivity.java` with `activity_main.xml` (let's call them MainActivity) and `SecondActivity.java` with activity_second.xml, you need to split the string based on the activity name. So you need to make:

- **strings_main.xml**
- **strings_second.xml**

in the strings_main.xml, you need to use `activityname_text` pattern. For example, if in the MainActivity you have a Title TextView then you need to add:

```
<string name="main_title">My Title</string>
```

For *untranslatable* string in MainActivity, you can add something like this:

```
<string name="main_app_name" translatable="false">MyAppName</string>
<string name="main_developer_name" translatable="false">My Developer Name</string>
```

This approach is suitable if you have a large project where each distinct Activity (or package) is maintained by another developer. And this approach will make sure you not accidentally alter the text for other Activity than your current edited Activity.

**For multiple language**, we just need to make a folder based on the language. For example, for Indonesia language we just need to add `values-in` folder. Then we can copy the strings xml from values folder. More for [Supporting Different Languages](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html?).

When adding a different language for an app (For example, Indonesia language), Android Studio will complaining about missing translation if there is a string in `values` but not in `values-in`. For example, if in `values` we have:

```
<string name="main_title">My Title</string>
```

But not exist in `values-in` then Android Studio will complaining about the non exist translation when Build-> Release the app. We can fix the error by adding `translatable=false`:

```
<string name="main_title" translatable="false">My Title</string>
```

We also can change the translation because there is Translation Editor in Android Studio.

**For project naming convention**, you can look at [Ribot android-guidelines](https://github.com/ribot/android-guidelines/blob/master/project_and_code_guidelines.md).

Comment: This approach is not suitable if you want to support multiple languages

Comment: For multiple language, we just need to make a folder based on the language. For example, for Indonesia language we just need to add `values-in` folder. Then we can copy the strings xml from values folder.

Comment: I like this, It makes sence and it feels like an answer, if the project is large right. It´s also scalable who knows how big your project gets

Answer (score -1):

It all depends on your preferences. And there is really many ways of storing Strings. As many as coding styles.

- One way: store all in strings.xml . This can be OK for small project,
  but when quantity of strings will be over 50, all'll look messed up.
- **Second way**: store by usage purpose. Something like login_error_strings.xml and so on. This idea is described [here](http://jeroenmols.com/blog/2016/03/07/resourcenaming/)
- Third way: store in static fields. Create some `Const.class` and put there all what do you want. I don't really know what is drawback of it, but there is diffidently something wrong.

Just to clarify: I think that "second way" is best way of doing this.

Comment: It doesn't really depend on preference. Any sane developer will put all resource strings in strings.xml, to allow for multiple languages

Comment: Yea if that is true, then there´s no question about what approche to use

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes, but some `Strings` isn't translatable and just technical `String`s.

Comment: care to give an example of a string that is not translatable?

Comment: @TimCastelijns App name? Some server url? Regex pattern? Plenty of them.

Comment: Alright, yes. But not every string should be placed in strings.xml, only the ones that are displayed to the user. The app name is translatable. Server url and regex patterns do not belong in strings.xml because as you said they are "technical strings"

Comment: @TimCastelijns so what did I say wrong?) Store in strings.xml <50, in named xmls for more. And naming or quantity of strings in one xml depend on your personal preferences.

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd approach both do not support multiple languages. 1st option remains. *when quantity of strings will be over 50, all'll look messed up.* messed up is subjective. You can apply structure in strings.xml perfectly fine

Comment: @TimCastelijns why 2nd isn't translatable? It translates as any value in strings.xml. As long as .xml file have <resources> and <string> tags, it will be translated.

Comment: Imagine you have to translate the app for 20 languages. Normally you then have 20 strings.xml files, but if you choose to split up the files as option 2 suggests, you now have a so called file explosion.

Comment: @TimCastelijns so find balance between file number and string number per file. Don't create file for every activity/fragment, create for big categories. I'll greatly increase your convenience.

Comment: Look  at this [Xabber](https://github.com/redsolution/xabber-android/tree/master/xabber/src/main/res) project how the text strings are stored in files named after where there occur. Can this be done using android studio automation tool -translation editor?

Comment: @ErikHellberg: I don't know about Automation tool for Translation, but there is built in Translation Editor in Android Studio.

Comment: @ErikHellberg it done automatically by Android Studio. When you create at least one translation it will create folder with values for this translation.